# Change default font for input

Tags: macos, font, input-source

I have a font that I use with a custom input to use my own glyphs. Is it possible (and if so how) to set the default font for this input to use across my OS (in a similar fashion to how the Japanese input works)?

Comment: The Japanese input uses the Hiragino font wherever I type. I want my input to do the same, but with a different font.

Comment: The way my input works is it takes 1, 2, 3, or 4 chars and turns them into a symbol or accented char. These are represented in my font with my glyphs, so it works like Japanese. If I don't use my font it just displays the symbols/accented chars rendering my setup sort of useless.

Comment: You could try putting your glyphs at the codepoints for a specific language and changing the default font for that language to your font in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Frameworks/CoreText.fra mework/Resources/DefaultFontFallbacks.plist  .  Here is another way of  changing the system fonts in general:  https://github.com/twardoch/fonttools-utils/tree/master/mac-os-x-system-font-replacer

Comment: Not really in favor of disabling SIP though.